# Show $x^5+x^4+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{2})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I have proved that $f(x)=x^5+x^4+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, so it's irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$, hence in $\mathbb{Q}$.

I know $f(x)=x^5+x^4+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{2})$ $\iff$ $x^5-2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha), f(\alpha)=0 $, but I cannot make progress anymore.

Comment: One option is to prove that the polynomial is not solvable by radicals over $F=\mathbb{Q} $ and thus also not solvable by radicals over $K=F(\sqrt[5]{2})$ (as $K$ is a radical extension of $F$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2$ is totally ramified in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]{2})$, because $\sqrt[5]{2}^5=2$. It follows that $\mathcal O_{\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]{2})}/(\sqrt[5]{2})=\Bbb F_2 $.  Thus by the reduction criterion, irreducibility over $\Bbb F_2 $ implies irreducibility over $\mathcal O_{\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]{2})}$ and this implies irreducibility over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]{2})$.